# How do you programmatically set a custom title via a Views display using PHP?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to set a custom title for my Views display by programmatically doing a `drupal_set_title()` within the Global PHP footer. But it seems that its not firing as I think its firing before the page is rendered.

How can I programmatically set the title of the page using Global PHP within the footer? I want to tap into the results data to create a custom title using `drupal_set_title()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "Global PHP footer"?  Are you talking about a footer region?  A footer template file?
You could certainly do this in a views pre render function.

Comment: no i mean the footer section of the view display. where it says header / footer. you can insert a PHP field in there.

Comment: I would recommend disabling the PHP input filter and moving any of your custom PHP to either a custom theme or a module.  This is good advice from the bots,  http://www.lullabot.com/blog/articles/drupal-input-formats-and-filters

Comment: i understand i can take the route of making a module to do this simple task, but it is just that, a simple task. All i want is to set a title nothing more. im particularly looking to just set the title without having to create extra files I need to keep track of.